# How to convert a text file to csv when the text file name is to be read from some other file?

Tags: python, pandas, linux, csv

I have a file "list_csv" , which contains the file names as following:

hierarchy1.rpt
hierarchy2.rpt

I want to read the convert the above rpt files into csv.

I tried the following code:
file2 = open('list_csv', 'r')
Lines1 = file2.readlines()
for line in Lines1:
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv(line)
read_file.to_csv(line)

But it errored out as:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'hierarchy2.rpt\n' does not exist: b'hierarchy1.rpt\n'

Comment: You need to `.strip` the lines to get rid of the newlines.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the list of file names
with open('list_csv', 'r') as file2:
    Lines1 = file2.readlines()

# Loop through the file names
for line in Lines1:
    # Remove newline character
    line = line.strip()
    
    # convert it to CSV
    dataframe1 = pd.read_csv(line)
    
    # Save as a CSV file
    dataframe1.to_csv(line.replace('.rpt', '.csv'), index=False)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The csv file still has space characters only, not commas. I am not sure what is missing.

Comment: Why don't you give the example files to check @AakritiGoel

Comment: Hi, the file format is like:                                                                        
  1561539445.000    99.83  99.84   7.43  66.67 
  1561542382.500    87.46  92.66  41.48  43.49 
  1561545320.500    91.19  94.46  37.16  46.19 
  1561548258.000    98.02  98.04   0.92  76.47 
  1561551195.500    97.91  97.93   0.78  86.67

Comment: @AakritiGoel, this does not help. Upload your csv and share the link to your csv